# Patching pvc coated rain pants?

Tags: toxic-chemicals, repair

Due to wear my rain pants have started leaking.
The pants are made of polyamide with pvc coating. The pvc coating is peeling of in the crotch area, as this is where a lot of friction happens when cycling.

Because during normal use there is no friction on the rest of the garment, I suspect the pants could be used for another year at least if I patch the leaky area. I have a glue used for fixing tent-seams.

Is there anything I should be aware of, in terms of combinations of materials and glue, if I try to patch the garment?

Comment: You might get more answers at [outdoors.se, where reproofing has been discussed quite a bit](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/search?q=reproofing)